# What is the best free plugin for Eclipse that allows for formatting/indenting/cleanup of JSP code?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, intellij-idea

I know that IntelliJ has an option to select all the code in a JSP file, right click, and select "format". This nicely formats all HTML, CSS, scriptlets and JSTL tags in a JSP file.

Can Eclipse do this?

If not, what is the best free Eclipse plugin that does the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the Web Tool Plateform plateform (on eclipse.org website), this is very simple : in the JSP editor tab, right click->source->format (or Shift+Ctrl+F)

Comment: The formatter in the WTP usually works pretty poorly for me - and I don't think there is any way to configure it like the regular Java formatter.

Comment: yah, the formatter in WTP has broken pages on me numerous times.

Answer (score 4):

I use the EclipseHTMLEditor from [Project Amateras](http://amateras.sourceforge.jp/). Be sure to set "Amateras JSP Editor" as default editor for file type "*.jsp" in Window > Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations.

**UPDATE:** As of today, March 27th 2015, Project Amateras seems stale. However [latest releases of WTP](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) are much improved and surely worth a try. Thanks to @Vogel612 for the info.

Comment: There has been no maintenance (or activity) on that website since December 2012 :(

Comment: @Vogel612, I'm not working with JSP anymore... Have you tried the [latest WTP](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/)? Maybe it's much better now than how it was back in 2010.

Comment: Actually I have not :( I have isntalled veloeclipse instead for a proper highlighting (unfortunately no indentation mechanism... maybe I should ;)

Comment: Sooo.. I have installed and tested WTP now. It seems to me that the default formatting can be slightly quirky at times, but all in all it works wonderfully. You get a whole bunch of syntax highlight and formatting options presented in a simple and clean way.  I'd say it looks good :)

Answer (score 1):

I found this one on eclipse plugin central.

Looks like an all in one kind of formatter. I haven't tried it myself but it might be what you are looking for

[NXFormat](http://www.eclipseplugincentral.com/Web_Links-index-req-viewlink-cid-926.html)

Comment: Looks good, but not free

Comment: Link leads to youtube as of now.