# Eclipse plugin for Facelets files

Tags: eclipse, jsf, autocomplete, eclipse-plugin, facelets

I have checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239739/what-is-the-best-free-plugin-for-eclipse-that-allows-for-formatting-indenting-cle) but it seems outdated now. Are there any plugins for Eclipse that supports Facelets/XHTML files and eases the development?

Comment: Format? Anyway, related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204807/how-to-see-docs-for-jsf-facelets-elements-in-eclipse

Comment: That was indeed to get your attention ;) and you link does solve it for me since I mean following you blog to get upto speed . If you answer it I will accept it . By the way to you use Glassfish at work as well.

Comment: I posted it as an answer. I use Glassfish (and Tomcat) for hobby and quick development only. Glassfish is blazing fast in hotpublishing/hotdeployments. For the current project we're using JBoss AS in production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the [Glassfish Eclipse Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204807/how-to-see-docs-for-jsf-facelets-elements-in-eclipse/6204960#6204960) and the [JBoss Tools Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057328/how-do-i-install-jboss-6-in-eclipse-helios-jee/4057346#4057346) supports Facelets files and autocompletion of JSF tags. The JBoss Tools Plugin also adds [EL autocompletion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276254/el-proposals-in-facelets-with-eclipse/6278459#6278459) support to this.

The Glassfish Eclipse Plugin only works when your target runtime is set to [Glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net) and the JBoss Tools Plugin only works when your target runtime is set to [JBoss AS](http://jboss.org/jbossas). JBoss AS is deep under the covers the same as Tomcat (which is just a simple Servlet container), but then enriched with a lot of additional Java EE aspects such as JSF, EJB, JAX-WS/RS, JMS, etc.

Comment: Yes I only used glassfish after going through your tutorial and it is outstanding wonder why not commonly used in production.